# Gmsh mesh parallel execution in fipy

Tags: fipy

I am trying to solve parallel on a gmsh mesh. While loading the .geo file, an error occurs,

```
"raise EnvironmentError("Gmsh version must be >= 2.0.")"
```

My installed gmsh version is 2.8.3, (I have also tried 2.13, 2.10, nothing works)

The parallel.py file in the example is executing properly and the meshes are properly parallelized. But when I try to load a .geo file using Gmsh3D in the same parallel.py file, I get the above error however executing in serial seems fine.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which version of FiPy are you using? Maybe this fix might help, https://github.com/usnistgov/fipy/issues/462. Also, there a number of threads on the mailing list that might help, see https://www.mail-archive.com/search?l=all&q=gmsh+EnvironmentError, mostly to do with the Gmsh path being incorrect.

Comment: Thank you, I searched through mailing list and got some hints. Finally fixed the issue by shifting the install location of GMSH from usr/bin to usr/local/bin. Also, I manually added the gmsh version in the gmshmesh.py file, due to some problems in recognising GMSH-2.13.2.