# Problems with Version Gmsh (version >=2) and Fipy

Tags: python, mesh, pde, fipy

I am new in [FiPy](https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/) and I have problems with the example:

examples.diffusion.circle: https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/examples/diffusion/generated/examples.diffusion.circle.html

I get the error:

```
EnviromentError: Gmsh version must be >=2.0
```

I tried already some things that were posted about two years ago, but that did not help, e.g.,
[EnvironmentError: Gmsh version must be >= 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45405916/environmenterror-gmsh-version-must-be-2-0)
and [Gmsh mesh parallel execution in fipy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39831494/gmsh-mesh-parallel-execution-in-fipy)

I already checked my versions:
Fipy: 3.3
pygmsh: 5.0.2
spyder 3.3.6
Python: 2.7
gmsh: 4.1.1

I am working on Windows 10 64Bit.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: It would help if you listed the things that you already tried (maybe link to the post from two years ago). And you'll also get more help if you post some of the code that's not working. At best, a minimal, reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: What is the result of typing `gmsh -version` at the command line?

Comment: @Druckles, thank you for your advice. Here are the posts from two years ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45405916/environmenterror-gmsh-version-must-be-2-0. And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39831494/gmsh-mesh-parallel-execution-in-fipy.

Comment: @jeguyer, the version of gmsh is 4.1.1

Comment: My guess is that gmsh is not on the execution path when you run FiPy. Try `gmsh -version` from within the Spyder environment.

Comment: @jeguyer: thank you very much. You were right.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EnvironmentError: Gmsh version must be >= 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45405916/environmenterror-gmsh-version-must-be-2-0)

Answer (score 1):

Like jeguyer mentioned: gmsh must be on the execution path when runs FiPy. That solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I copied the entirely **gmsh** folder into the ***Anaconda3\Scripts***  folder and since then everything worked fine.

For specific instructions: [EnvironmentError: Gmsh version must be >= 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45405916/environmenterror-gmsh-version-must-be-2-0/45451493#45451493)